# Double join on same table produces wrong result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Basically I have a `Driver` model that has many `rides`. Those `rides` has `price` field and I want to calculate driver's `total_paid` (the payment they have earned for all the time) and `this_week_paid` (the payment has been done only from the beginning of this week to the end of it) in one active record query.

I have achieved the correct number for `total_paid` part easily with one join like this:

```
Driver.joins(:rides).
  select("#{Driver.table_name}.*, sum(substring(rides.price from '[0-9]+.[0-9]*')::numeric) as total_paid").
  group("#{Driver.table_name}.id").
  order("total_paid DESC, id")
```

Now when I try to add `this_week_paid` to that query:

```
Driver.joins("INNER JOIN rides this_week_rides ON #{Driver.table_name}.id = this_week_rides.driver_id").
  joins("INNER JOIN rides all_rides ON #{Driver.table_name}.id = all_rides.driver_id").
  select("#{Driver.table_name}.*, " +
             "sum(substring(this_week_rides.price from '[0-9]+.[0-9]*')::numeric) as this_week_paid, " +
             "sum(substring(all_rides.price from '[0-9]+.[0-9]*')::numeric) as total_paid").
  where(this_week_rides: { created_at: Time.current.beginning_of_week..Time.current.end_of_week }).
  group("#{Driver.table_name}.id").
  order("this_week_paid DESC, id")
```

It runs without throwing any exceptions however, interestingly the `total_paid` field is two times of correct number and `this_week_paid` field is three times of the correct one ( Query answer: `{ this_week_paid: 188.46, total_paid: 159.9 }`, the correct answer: `{ this_week_paid: 62.82, total_paid: 79.95 }` ).

I did try to add `where("this_week_rides.id != all_rides.id")` and it gives me another wrong result (`"this_week_paid" => 125.64,"total_paid" => 97.08`)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You join the same table twice and that will multiply the number of rows you get so that is why you get multiples of the expected result. Just join it once and filter in the select like this:

```
sum(substring(rides.price from '[0-9]+.[0-9]*')::numeric) filter (
  where rides.created_at between time1 and time2
) as this_week_paid,

sum(substring(rides.price from '[0-9]+.[0-9]*')::numeric) as total_paid
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that.

Comment: Happy to help! Another effect of the query is that it filters out drivers that didn't have a ride this week. An inner join that doesn't match anything is like multiplying the number of rows with 0. The "substring(rides.price" seems strange to me, but maybe that is just some experimentation?

Comment: Yeap, just like you said. Also eliminating the drivers who don't have any ride during this week is what I want for now. TY again and happy new year.